# Efficiently Propagating Interface Changes in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, interface

As I delve into the world of decoupling and dependency injection, I'm finding myself writing more and more interfaces.  I try my best to create interfaces knowing exactly how I'm going to use them, but there's always the case that I end up implementing the interface and then changing how it's used.

I've become accustomed to VS' automatic refactoring ability.  But I've found that it doesn't support propagating interface changes automatically to the implementing classes.  Is there a way to do this automatically so I'm not copying and pasting until my compile errors go away?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wanted to come back and answer this question:

If you want to change an interface method name, if you change it from the instantiating class, Visual Studio will give you the option to propagate it to the interface (as well as all other calls throughout your code, as normal).  If you change the method name in the interface definition, the change will not propagate to the instantiating classes.

Answer (score 0):

Since Visual Studio, or any other tool can't "know" what the implementation should be, it falls to you, the developer to implement it.

If you change an interface definition, it is a *good* thing that compilation fails until you have implemented the change.

Comment: I agree that I want compilation to break, it just seems like a trivial task that Visual Studio could do to have my interface changes propagated throughout the implementers, just like when I change a variable or class name.

Comment: @GarrisonNeely - If you add a member to your interface, how would that propagate? If you add a formal parameter?